# Search and replace date between characters without deleting the 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good afternoon,

I am not an expert on excel and would like some help with a formula, I am trying to add "+1" to a date in between characters. it looks like `_mmddyyy_` I want to add `"+1"` to the year then add it to the file name path, my issues is when I do then it is removing the `"0"` at.

B46 = full file name

D46 = the number of charaters on B46

_02021988_12515_2019.xlsx

```
=SEARCH(C46,B46)

=IFERROR(REPLACE(B46,D46,8,(LEFT(C46,8)+"+1")),B46)
```

and it is coming back as

_2021989_203620004_2019.xlsx

Comment: don't use LEFT.  use MID instead and pull out the year you want to modify, then add the 1 and then add it back.  The 0 is disappearing because Excel does not track leading zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula will add 1 to the year in the first part of the file name.  That is if the year starts in the 6th character position and is 4 characters long.

```
=LEFT(B46,5)&MID(B46,6,4)+1&RIGHT(B46,LEN(B46)-9)
```

[image: POC]